# Keep Title and Text on First Page in Latex with Custom '/maketitle'

Tags: titles, page-breaking

I'm trying to get a custom title block, and tried to rework 'maketitle' and I think I did something wrong. How do I get the body text to start on the same page as the title? (and any other obvious errors you see?)

I'm not sure the document class needed that much, mostly I just wanted a custom title block on a single column article, and the text to start on the same page as the title. Looks like it created a title page instead?

```
\documentclass[journal,onecolumn]{article}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper, portrait, margin=1in}
\onecolumn

\usepackage{setspace}
\author{Me}
\title{Stuff}

%% Rework the Title Block
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
    \twocolumn[%
    \begin{spacing}{0.9}
    \textbf{DOCUMENT 001}\\
    This is a Header on Title Page Only\\
    role
     \end{spacing}
\textbf{\begin{center}This Is My Report Title\end{center}}
\vskip 0.5in
]
\noindent
LEFT SIDE BLOCK\\
LEFT SIDE TEXT\\
LEFT SIDE MORE TEXT\\

\newpage
RIGHT SIDE BLOCK\\
RIGHT SIDE TEXT\\
RIGHT SIDE MORE TEXT\\
\onecolumn
}
%% END custom MAKETITLE

\doublespacing
\begin{document}

\maketitle


This is the first paragraph, not in a section yet, but should be just below the title block.
\section{Default \LaTeX{} layout}
\blindtext[2]

\subsection{Some dummy text}
\blindtext[2]


\section{Some dummy text}
\blindtext[3]

Text about stuff. And more stuff. and more text. 

\section{Some dummy text}
\blindtext[1]

Text about stuff. And more stuff. and more text. 


\end{document}
```